# Writing first angular app. How should I architect this?

Tags: architecture, angularjs, controller

I'm writing my first angular app after messing around with some basic todo type apps and am curious at what would be the proper way to architect the controllers from a high level.

The app will allow the users to dynamically add/remove homes from a plot and each home can have rooms in it and each room within that home can have products in it. Homes, rooms and products can all be added/removed on the fly and rooms from one home can be moved into other homes.

My first pass at it has me thinking I'll need a controller for homes (collection of all homes), then a controller for each individual home. The same will go for rooms and products; a controller for all rooms and then a controller for each room.

Is this the best way to do this? I'm coming at this from a backbone perspective but want to follow the guidelines that angular would prescribe but don't see anything online doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first think about your models, then your views, then lastly, your controllers.

Your models should probably be in services, not controllers.  (This way, if multiple views need access to the same model data, the controllers associated with those views can simply inject the service(s) to get access to the shared data/model.)

Break up your page(s) into separate views.  Attach a controller to each view, and have the controller get only the model data it needs from the injected service(s) so that the view can do its job.  Make controllers as thin as possible.

(Much of the above is from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14994393/215945) I wrote.)